# Duplicate albums are appearing in Apple Music on iOS after editing metadata of purchases

Tags: data-synchronization, music, apple-music

I manually manage my music library on my Mac outside of Apple Music, and sync it with my iPhone.

Unfortunately, as I have edited the metadata of past iTunes purchases, Apple Music on iOS is showing the manually edited record, plus the iTunes version, which it thinks is different.

Manually edited record:

[image]

Duplicate iTunes version:

[image]

When shuffling music, it's playing the same tracks twice. How can I hide these iTunes versions in the most efficient way possible? Is it literally a case of going through and manually removing each from the library? They don't appear in Apple Music on Mac. I've tried looking for iTunes Match settings, which I vaguely recall from the past, but can't find them anymore.